# Linux скрипт на создание папки с указанным пользователем именем

Tags: linux, bash

Какие команды нужно использовать чтобы создать папку через терминал и указать её имя?

Comment: Все уже есть (mkdir)

Comment: Познакомьтесь `man mkdir`

Answer (score 4):

Просто создать папку:

```
mkdir name
```

Можно указать полный или относительный путь до создаваемой папки

```
mkdir /home/username/fizz
mkdir ~/buzz
mkdir name/surname
```

Можно создавать сразу несколько

```
mkdir foo bar bazz
```

Но если такая папка уже есть, то вы получите сообщение об ошибке.

```
mkdir foo
mkdir foo
mkdir: foo: File exists
```

С ключом `-p` можно создавать вложенную структуру. К тому же, если папка уже есть, теперь это не будет считаться ошибкой.

```
mkdir -p /fizz/buzz/bar
```

С ключом `-m` можно сразу задать права доступа на создаваемую папку

```
mkdir -m 0600 restricted
```

Прочитать примерно то же самое в своем терминале:

```
man mkdir
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash/

echo "Введите имя папки:"
read dirname
mkdir ~/$dirname
```

Скрипт создаёт папку в домашней директории пользователя.